# Obfuscation VBA Excel - Break Line, Var Names

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Im trying to build my own Obfuscation add-in for my VBA projects.

I started with the easier tasks:

- Remove Blank Lines
- Remove Indentts
- Remove Comments

I could figure out how to do this things, maybe not in the best way, but im stuck in:

- Insert Random Break Lines (" _")

I would like to have this working for diferent types of delimiter, for now im only working with "=" signal. By the way, i have problems when i have multiple delimiters in the line (Eg: If bla = "abc" or ble = "acd"). The code causes incorrects splits in my line.

```
Sub VBE_Break_The_Lines()
Dim VBC As VBComponent
Dim a, i, j, lCount As Long
Dim str As String
Dim temp As Variant
lCount = 0
i = 1
Dim blnStringMode, blnLineContinue As Boolean
    For Each VBC In VBProjToClean.VBComponents
        blnStringMode = False
        i = 1
        With VBC.CodeModule
            Do Until i > .CountOfLines
                If Not .ProcOfLine(i, vbext_pk_Proc) = "VBE_Remove_Comments" Then
                    str = .Lines(i, 1)
                End If

                If InStr(1, str, " = ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    temp = Split(str, " = ")
                    .InsertLines i, ""
                    .ReplaceLine i, temp(0) & " _"
                    .InsertLines i + 1, "= " & temp(1)
                    .DeleteLines i + 2
                    lCount = lCount + 1
                    'a = InStr(1, str, "=", vbTextCompare)
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            i = i + 1
            Loop
        End With
    Next
MsgBox lCount & "  LINES BREAKED ( = )", , strFileToClean

End Sub
```

My next step will be change procedure/variable names, but not sure if REGEX should be the best way, i just read a lot, but not sure yet.

Hope you guys can give me a way to follow

Comment: Is this an exercise to learn about obfuscation, or are you trying to secure your VBA?

Comment: This is an exercise but also i am trying to secure my vba. My vba code is not any comercial kind of code, i share a lot macro with colleagues. The last time they broke my vba pw (i know its easy), i also understand that obfuscation in vba isnt the best security mechanism, but im sure it will prevent a lot of ppl.

Comment: Gene, only temp is variant, but i dont understand how your comment can help in this question.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Why not start with [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/invisiblebasic/) Open Source code and make a new build from that instead of reinventing the wheel?

You need to change all the file extensions in the code from `.xls` to `.xlsm`, save the IB_test.xls workbook as a macro-enabled workbook and save the addin as `.xlam`, not `.xla` to make this work, but even though the code is 9 years old, it still works in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If you are into VBA obfuscation, you may want to try out VBASH (www.ayedeal.com/vbash). It is pretty straight forward and powerful.